# How do i Put the window on top and refresh the back window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is the thing happening .I click on submit button it goes to some.php and gets the json value with item2 and we open print.php in a new window .After that the page which generated print.php gets refreshed with a function. Now my problem i want to retain the print.php window on the top and also refresh the back window which generated it .So i went and used `window.location = self.location();`.Now my print.php stays on top but the page which needs to be refreshed gives me error `"object doesnot support this action"`

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){
   $.post("some.php?id="+id1value,function(data){
          if(data.item2 !=null){
             window.open('print.php?id1='+id1value+'&id2='+ data.item2 );
              refreshBack($("#div1").text());
           }else{
              //Do Process for else
            } },'json')  

   }         
)
});

function refreshBack(text){
if(text==="abc"){
url = "one.php";
}
else{
url = 'two.php?id3='+id3value;
}
document.form_name.action=url;
document.form_name.submit();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To refresh the owning window that launched a popup, use:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

To refresh a child window, save the reference made by window.open() and later call the reference's location reload.

```
var myPopup = window.open('print.php?id1='+id1value+'&id2='+ data.item2 );

...

myPopup.location.reload();
```

To give a particular window foreground focus, use the .focus() method in either window object.

```
// Focus the current window
window.focus();

// Focus the child window
myPopup.focus();

// Focus the window that opened the current popup
window.opener.focus();
```